# Flatten a tree to a collection of nodes

Tags: c#, linq, tree, lazy

I have implemented simple tree class as follows:

```
public class MoveTreeNode
{
    public MoveTreeNode Parent
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private List<MoveTreeNode> children = new List<MoveTreeNode>();

    public IEnumerable<MoveTreeNode> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return children;
        }
    }

    public void Add(MoveTreeNode child)
    {
        child.Parent = this;
        children.Add(child);
    }

    private IEnumerable<MoveTreeNode> Flatten()
    {
        yield return this;

        foreach(var child in Children.Select(x=> x.Flatten()).SelectMany(x=>x))
        {
            yield return child;
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but I have concerns about the following line:

`foreach(var child in Children.Select(x=> x.Flatten()).SelectMany(x=>x))`

Since I'm using `yield` I'd prefer to gain some of the benefits of [lazy evaluation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/pedram/lazy-evaluation-in-c) but I fear that while each child of the root will be lazily evaluated, the childrens' children, etc will be evaluated at once when their parents are evaluated.

Is there some way I can refactor this to make the most of lazy evaluation, or am I better off leaving it this way?

Comment: what is the following line?

Comment: Oops, missed a line. Added in now.

Comment: Is there a limitation on how deep your tree can be? Else you might run into a stack overflow with this algorithm.

Comment: There is a technical limit in how I create the tree, however you are correct that if I were to ever refactor this to be an all-purpose tree, I would have to  consider a linear algorithm, probably along with loop checks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want to flatten each child in turn:

```
private IEnumerable<MoveTreeNode> Flatten()
{
    yield return this;

    foreach (var node in Children.SelectMany(child => child.Flatten()))
    {
        yield return node;
    }
}
```

That way you won't flatten the whole tree first.

Edit:

It's more difficult to talk about things so let's look at some code. SelectMany is roughly equal to:

```
public static IEnumerable<TOut> SelectMany<T, TOut>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<TOut>> selector)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        foreach (var subItem in selector(item))
        {
            yield return subItem;
        }
    } 
}
```

So as you can see, we will definitely get all of the nodes and if you stop iterating before the end (e.g. by calling `.First()`) you will only call `Flatten()` on a single child.

Comment: I always forget about the more useful functionality that `SelectMany` has, thank you. Will the `foreach` loop still stop the `SelectMany` clause from being lazily evaluated?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "fully evaluated". `SelectMany` will return an `IEnumerable<MoveTreeItem>` which will be lazily evaluated.

Comment: I'm wondering if, by iterating over this `IEnumerable` using `foreach`, the contents of the `IEnumerable` generated by `SelectMany` will all be evaluated before `Flatten` returns.

Comment: A `foreach` will cause evaluation, otherwise you can't loop in the first place. When you call `Flatten()`, the underlying selectManies will be evaluated instantly. Thus, each loop will have evaluated before Flatten returns.

Comment: @NickUdell - made an edit. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Also, regarding

> ```
> private List<MoveTreeNode> children = new List<MoveTreeNode>();
>
> public IEnumerable<MoveTreeNode> Children
> {
>     get
>     {
>         return children;
>     }
> }
> ```

Another way to do it would be to have

```
public IEnumerable<MoveTreeNode> Children
{
    get;
    private set;
}
```

but then you'd have to initialize it in the constructor.